# VS Setup installer doesn't include exe if app targets net461 and netcoreapp

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, setup-project

I have a simple solution in VS that contains a Console app targeting `netcoreapp2.0` and `net461`:

**ConsoleTest.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I also have a VS Setup installer project for this console app that is configured to include "Primary output from Control (Active)" of type "Output" in my Application Folder:

[image]

Whenever I build and run this installer (targeting `net461`), it only includes `ConsoleTest.dll` in the application folder output:

[image]

If I remove the target framework reference to `netcoreapp2.0` in `ConsoleTest.csproj` and only target `net461`, I get the proper `ConsoleTest.exe` output from the installer that I need:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

It seems that when targeting both `netcoreapp2.0` and `net461` that the setup installer will always choose the output from `netcoreapp2.0`. Since this is a windows installer I need the `net461` output with the exe.

How do I properly target `net461` output for my windows setup installer while still being able to have both target frameworks present in the console project?

Answer (score 2):

If your app requires .NET 461 on the system then you specify that in the setup project. In View-Editor-Launch Conditions there's .NET FW dropdown choice where you specify the 461 version (I'm in VS 2017 Community Edition).

Using Primary Output often seems unpredictable. Just drag and drop the files from Explorer into the Application Folder, or right click in the Application Folder pane and add files.

Comment: I just checked and .NET Framework 4.6.1 is already set under launch conditions, so that doesn't seem to affect anything. I suppose I will have to direct add files instead of using primary output, though that seems rather brute force and doesn't work well for various build configurations (ex. Debug vs Release).